# How to control field visibility for Public group

Tags: security, sharing, public-group

I have a custom field on a custom object, that field needs to be editable for a public group and for rest of the users/profile this should be read only.

How would I manage to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

Groups are associated with data visibility (roles, sharing etc.) whereas you're talking about [field level security](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/customize_layoutoverview.htm) which is associated with profiles, so this approach won't work easily. You would have to either rely on page layouts or complex control through Apex, neither of which I'd recommend.

What you should do is create a profile with the base level of access required on those fields i.e. read-only, and they use [permission sets](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/perm_sets_overview.htm) to grant the requisite users write access.

Comment: I think Validation rule may also be applied to handle this problem by creating a check box on User level ( to determine whether logged in user belongs to specific Public Group or not)

Comment: @CodeSpokes that doesn't make any sense. Validation rules do not control who can access specific fields on an object. That is field level security. Field level security and validation rules are two completely separate things. I agree with Wes, permission sets are what you need here.